# HTML5 video error handling

Tags: html, error-handling, html5-video

I need to tell, whether video cannot be played ("x" sign is shown in browser).

This code does't works. "onerror" event will never be fired under Firefox

```
var v = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
    if ( v != undefined )
        v.onerror = function(e) {
            if ( v.networkState == v.NETWORK_NO_SOURCE )
            {
                // handle error
            }
        }
```

What's wrong here ?

Answer (score 29):

"onerror" is not a valid event type for `<video>`

Use "error" instead.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].addEventListener('error', function(event) { ... }, true);
```

For a complete list of events for `<video>` go here: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_audio_and_video_in_Firefox

Comment: Its return undefined, I recommend using jQuery `$('video')[0].addEventListener`...

Answer (score 26):

From Firefox 4 onwards, the 'error' event is [dispatched on the `<source>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Error_handling).

And you should add an error handler **on the only/last source**:

### HTML

```
<video id="vid" controls>
  <source src="dynamicsearch.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
  <source src="otherdynamicsearch.avi" type="video/avi"></source>
</video>
```

### JS

```
var v = document.querySelector('video#vid');
var sources = v.querySelectorAll('source');

if (sources.length !== 0) {
    var lastSource = sources[sources.length-1];

    lastSource.addEventListener('error', function() {
        alert('uh oh');
    });
}
```

### JQuery

```
$('video source').last().on('error', function() {
    alert('uh oh');
});
```

### AngularJS

You can create an error handling directive (or just use [ng-error](https://github.com/andrefarzat/ng-error)):

```
<video id="vid" controls>
  <source src="dynamicsearch.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
  <source src="otherdynamicsearch.avi" type="video/avi" ng-error="handleError()"></source>
</video>
```

Where the error handling directive's `link` function should do (copied from ng-error):

```
element.on('error', function(event) {
    scope.$apply(function() {
        fn(scope, {$event:event});
    });
});
```

Comment: The link no longer contains the word "error" and I'm having trouble finding any information about this.

Answer (score 9):

It's good to know that Chrome and Firefox have different `onerror` callbacks. The error must therefore be mapped. Mozilla uses [error.originalTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/originalTarget).

Here is a sample on how to do it with pure JavaScript:

```js
const file = 'https://samples.ffmpeg.org/MPEG-4/MPEGSolution_jurassic.mp4';

window.fetch(file, {mode: 'no-cors'})
.then((response) => response.blob())
.then((blob) => {
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const video = document.createElement('video');      

  video.addEventListener('error', (event) => {
    let error = event;

    // Chrome v60
    if (event.path && event.path[0]) {
      error = event.path[0].error;
    }

    // Firefox v55
    if (event.originalTarget) {
      error = error.originalTarget.error;
    }

    // Here comes the error message
    alert(`Video error: ${error.message}`);

    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }, true);

  video.src = url;
  document.body.appendChild(video);
});
```

The above example maps an incoming error event into a [MediaError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaError) which can be used to display an error playback message.

Comment: This is definitely a more complete answer! Solved my need for more detailed information in handling the error :)

Comment: Heads up for anyone using the standard `<video><source … /></video>` structure, the errors will actually happen on the `source` elements as @KennyKi shared. I’m also unable to get the error information from the source errors (testing on Chrome 79.0, Safari 13.0, and Firefox 71.0)

Answer (score 6):

To catch error event, you should use `video.addEventListener()`:

```
var video = document.createElement('video');
var onError = function() { // your handler};
video.addEventListener('error', onError, true);
...
// remove listener eventually
video.removeEventListener('error', onError, true);
```

Note that the 3rd parameter of `addEventListener` (on capture) should be set to true. Error event is typically fired from descendants of video element ( tags).

Anyway, relying on video tag to fire an `error` event is not the best strategy to detect if video has played. This event is not fired on some android and iOS devices.

The most reliable method, I can think of, is to listen to `timeupdate` and `ended` events. If video was playing, you'll get at least 3 timeupdate events. In the case of error, `ended` will be triggered more reliably than `error`.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the event listener to the  tag instead - I think the onerror attribute ("error" event) works on the source tag now, not the video tag.

Comment: Do you happen to know where to bind it to in FireFox as well? I'm trying to catch a video that doesn't play (404 or wrong format), in Chrome no problem, but FireFox refuses to give me control over the errors...

Answer (score -2):

Pug example

```
video(src= encodeURI(item.urlVideo), type='video/mp4'  onerror="myFunction('param',this)")
script(src='/javascripts/onerror.js')

function myFunction(param, me) { 
    console.log(me);
    me.poster = './images/placeholder.jpg'; }
```