# Non-Microsoft browser - How do I get the error code for a failure?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is some simple HTML and Javascript:

```
<html>
<body>
<video id="video1" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp444">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<script> 
var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1"); 
var onError = function() {
   if (myVideo.error == null)
   {
       alert('Unknown error'); // crap, only supported in ie
       return;
   }
   if (myVideo.error.code == 1)
   {
       //MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED
       alert(myVideo.error.code + " - fetching prcess aborted by user");
   }
   else if (myVideo.error.code == 2)
   {
       //MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK
       alert(myVideo.error.code + " - error occurred when downloading");
   }
   else if (myVideo.error.code == 3)
   {
       //MEDIA_ERR_DECODE
       alert(myVideo.error.code + " - error occurred when decoding");
   }
   else if (myVideo.error.code == 4)
   {
       //MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED 
       alert(myVideo.error.code + " - audio/video not supported");
   }
   else
   {
       alert(myVideo.error.code + " - Unknown");
   }
};
myVideo.addEventListener('error', onError, true);
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

This code works fine in all broswers that I've tested (IE11, Edge, Chrome, Firefox, the Chrome on my Android Phone).

What does NOT work is the error Property.  Only IE and Edge tell me which of the code's it is, where all other browsers just tell me it's an Unknown Error.  Which, I guess, makes sense, being that it is only supported in Microsoft products: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_error.asp

Is there anything I can do that gets me a little more description or reason as to why there was an error in the first place?

Of note: The type of "video/mp444" was typed on purpose.  That's how I am simulating one type of error.

Comment: Add the word "debugger" in your code and step through it, what do you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final argument to `.addEventListener()` indicates whether the event should be handled during the "**[capture](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)**" phase of the event raising process.  Depending on where the event is raised and where you want to handle the event, capturing/bubbling come into play. 99.999% of the time, we want `false` there (IE 8 and less don't even support capturing anyway), but in this case, the event does not bubble (log the event and you will see the `bubbles` property is `false`).

Now, in your code, you are using the `source` child element, and any errors will be triggered at that element. If you want to handle the event at a higher level (the `video` ancestor element), event capturing *must be used*, so your code that sets the event listener on the `video` element that uses the `true` value for the 3rd argument to `.addEventListener()` would be correct.

```
myVideo.addEventListener('error', onError, true);
```

However, given that you only have one `source`, you can eliminate this element and just set the `src` on the `video` element itself. This allows you to set the event handler directly on the object that will throw the event, and in that case, the 3rd argument should be `false` or omitted:

```
myVideo.addEventListener('error', onError, false);
```

or:

```
myVideo.addEventListener('error', onError);
```

As for your error handling function itself, under the DOM standard, the event handling function will be passed a single argument that references the event itself, so all your event handlers should be prepared to receive that argument. However, that built-in event won't have the `code` property you are looking for. Use `mediaElement.error.code` instead.

Also, you may want to refactor it into a `switch` statement, which is better suited for a single property/variable being checked for many possible values.

```js
var myVideo = document.querySelector("#video1");
myVideo.addEventListener('error', onError);

    function onError(evt) {
       var message = "";
       // The normal error event will not contain the error code
       switch (myVideo.error.code) {
         case null:
           message = 'Unknown error'; // crap, only supported in ie
           break;
         case 1:
           //MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED
           message = " - fetching process aborted by user";
           break;
         case 2:
           //MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK
           message = " - error occurred when downloading";
           break;
         case 3:
           //MEDIA_ERR_DECODE
           message = " - error occurred when decoding";
           break;
         case 4:
           //MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED 
           message = " - audio/video not supported";
           break;
         default:
           message = " - Unknown";
           break;
       }

       console.log(myVideo.error.code + message);
    };
```

```html
<video id="video1" width="320" height="240" controls src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: My apologies, but I don't think this is right at all.  I have no problem getting the error event.  The issue I have is that the error object isn't supported, except in Microsoft browsers.  So, I'm curious as to how people - in non-Microsoft browsers - get at the four different error codes.

Comment: In addition, before I ended up using addEventListener (to get the error event to fire - the only thing I found that consistently worked across all browsers) ... I read this thread from stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573461/html5-video-error-handling ...  and Ales Kotnik said the following for the third parameter: Note that the 3rd parameter of addEventListener (on capture) should be set to true. Error event is typically fired from descendatns of video element ( tags). ... so now that's a bit confusing for me!  As you say the opposite.

Comment: @JustLooking You are incorrect about the `error` event only being supported in Microsoft browsers. It is part of the [HTML5 standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/error) and is supported in all HTML5 compliant user agents (which is all modern browsers). Additionally, as I stated, the third parameter isn't supposed to be `true` - that explanation is wrong. The capture phase is generally not used at all.

Comment: Noted on the switch.  In no way was this production code.  Heck, I didn't even spell process right for case 1! lol.  I've never messed with the video tag before, and today I was learning to use it and it's events.  So I'm just slapping together code willy-nilly until I'm satisfied with all the events I need - one being to make sure there's an error event.

Comment: @JustLooking Additionally, I (and just about every other professional developer) would tell you not to do research on W3Schools.com as the site is known for inaccuracies. The [Mozilla Developer's Network](https://developer.mozilla.org) is a much better resource.

Comment: I'm talking about the error OBJECT or property, not the error event.  Again, the event fires.  And for all non-Microsoft browsers that alert will always say "unknown" as myVideo.error is null.  This is what told me that the error property/object was not supported in other browsers: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_error.asp

Comment: Anyhow, false, for that parameter - for me - causes the event to not fire in certain browsers.  It has to be true for the event to fire.  Regardless, I can't get additional information about why it fails.  For example, using the error property myVideo.error.  So how do people in non-Microsoft browsers get additional info about the error?

Comment: @JustLooking  See my updated answer that sets the error handling function to take an argument.

Comment: OK.  I have tried the function take an argument route.  I'm pretty sure, as I googled that.  But let me try again.

Comment: for a momentary second it was -1.  And again, my apologies, I took your latest code and changed it to false - and nothing works right.  I get no events in Firefox and Chrome and IE and Edge fire their event, but both said "unknown error".  It got worse! ... Meanwhile, I changed it back from false to true - that 3rd param - and now all browsers fire the event.  But with your new function, I only get unkonwn error for all browsers.

Comment: It seems to me that it needs to be true (3rd param) - I can show you.  I have a publicly exposed web server.  And again, non-Microsoft browsers don't seem to give you error info/property.

Comment: @JustLooking See my revamped answer, which clarified when you need `true` as the 3rd `.addEventListener()` argument value and when you don't as well as a working example (I'm using Chrome 54) that gets the error code.

Comment: The thing that fixed this for me (all browsers) was the use of your video tag.  Notice how my video tag wraps source tags?  And yours didn't?  Your video tag uses the src property.  Doing just that, made everything work fine.  I could use true or false for that 3rd parm.  Either way it fired off the event I needed.  I didn't need evt as a function parameter.  For example, even in your code you posted, you don't use it.  Your switch uses myVideo.error.code.  So you got me to the answer, but not in the way you think. It's all about not using that source tags.

Comment: @JustLooking I know. This is all explained in my answer.

Comment: Gave you the green check mark for your awesomeness.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Changing my original video tags from:

```
<html>
<body>
<video id="video1" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

to:

```
<html>
<body>  
<video id="video1" width="320" height="240" controls src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

seemed to work for me. I no longer can make an error by making the type video/mp444. Instead, I just point it to a video that doesn't exist - and that gets me error code 4. But it works in all browsers now. myVideo.error.code has a value and myVideo.error is no longer null.

I'm going to give the green check-mark to Scott Marcus for his awesomeness.

Comment: If you read my last edited answer I explain why combining the two elements works.