# Javascript: how to catch errors loading videos in video.play()?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

The [MDN docs on video.play](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide#Example_Handling_play_failures) detail how it returns a Promise in modern browsers and that it will be rejected if the video cannot be played.

In my tests, I have found that this works well for when a video is not played, because of autoplay policies issues, such as not being muted, **however**, I am also seeing that it does not get rejected if the URL for the video 404s or is of the wrong content type.

Is there any way to catch loading errors like this? Or would this be a feature request for Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and others?

I have a sample codepen here: https://codepen.io/mrcoles/pen/abzJPaQ

In it I generate videos based on the following configs:

```
const ROWS = [
  {
    title: 'Video URL is good',
    src: 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4',
    muted: true
  },
  {
    title: 'Video URL is a 404',
    src: '/DOES-NOT-EXIST.mp4',
    muted: true
  },
  {
    title: 'Video URL is a bad source type (HTML page instead of video)',
    src: 'https://www.example.com/',
    muted: true
  },
  {
    title: 'Video URL is good, but not muted',
    src: 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4',
    muted: false
  }
];
```

Here’s a screenshot of the results:

[image: screenshot of codepend]

Comment: You should wire up your error handler in the [onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/onerror) event. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573461/html5-video-error-handling) is a post regarding attaching to that event.

Comment: Excellent, thanks @AdamH! In some initial testing I attached it to the `video`, but I’m seeing in the link you posted that browsers now throw the errors on the `source` elements (and it should be checked on the final one).

Answer (score 0):

Failure to load files needs to be watched separately by attaching an "error" event to the source elements inside the video (or maybe the video if the src is specified directly on it without source elements).

```js
sourceElt.addEventListener('error', evt => {
  console.log('Error');
});
```

I updated my codepen to add an example with multiple source elements inside a video. Since videos elements are built to try multiple, you should only listen for errors on the last source element (or maybe sum errors until you match the # of sources—I haven’t verified if things can expect to run top down).

Helpful info was provided in comments by @AdamH pointing to this other post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33471125/376489