# How I handle errors on video load on MUI CardMedia

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I'm defining a video card in my application.
I want to catch and display errors to the user when video loading fails.

I could probably attach an event handler to the html video tag like mentioned in
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573461/html5-video-error-handling) but could I do it in a more "react\mui" way?

My component:

```
      <CardMedia
          component="video"
          ref={videoRef}
          src={`${videoUrlBase}/loop/stream/${currentLoop.id}`}
          onClick={handleFullScreen}
          onTimeUpdate={handleOnTimeUpdate}
          onEnded={() => setIsPlaying(false)}
          autoPlay
          loop
          }}
        />
```

Comment: and `<CardMedia onError={(e) => {...}} .../>`  isn't working for you?

Comment: It does thank you. the synthetic events didn't came to my mind (https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/events.html)